# Convert to using promises in DB wrapper module function with Bluebird

Tags: node.js, bluebird, node-mysql

I anticipate a callback hell is beginning to form in my code so I decided to start using promises. But I can't wrap my head around implementing it. For example I have a function:

```
    DB.prototype = {

            findUser: function (username) {

                this._pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

            if (err) { return callback(true, false); }

            connection.query('SELECT password_hash, password_salt FROM users WHERE email = ? AND admin = 1', username,
                function (err, rows) {

                    connection.release();

                    if (rows.length === 1) { callback(false, rows[0]); }
                    else { callback(false, false); }

                });

            connection.on('error', function () { callback(true, false); });

        });
    }

    };
```

**How would I adapt this to using promises instead of callbacks? And how would I use this adapted db.findUser() ?**

**EDIT:**
I got something working. It looks like this:

```
DB.prototype = {

    getConnection: function() {
        return this._pool.getConnectionAsync();
    }

}
```

And the usage:

```
Promise.using(db.getConnection(), function(connection) {

    return connection.queryAsync("SELECT password_hash, password_salt FROM users WHERE email = ? AND admin = 1", "exampleUser")

        .then(function(rows) {
            connection.release();
            console.log("is there a row?", rows.length === 1, rows);
            // do something with results
        });

}).catch(function(err) {
    // This is only run if an error is thrown
    console.log("error is", err);
});
```

**Is this a good implementation or could something be improved?**

Comment: It looks like you need to promisfy connection.query. See https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function.

Comment: It sounds like Mike is probably right. By promisifying, it wraps the function which adds the promise .then()/.finally() functionality.

Comment: I used:
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);